# how can i select suppliers based on oldest date?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a ecommerce project and want to select suppliers based on oldest date...Here is my **DB design**

**Product**

```
id(PK) name            price  added_date(DATE)
1      Samsung Note    180000  2016-09-30
2      Nokia Lumia 510 215000  2016-09-29
```

**Supplier**

```
id(PK) name     registered_date(timestamp) stock
1  Easyshop 2016-09-30 12:50:12             10
2  T-mobile 2016-09-30 12:55:36             10
```

**product_supplier**

```
itemid(pk) supplierid(pk)
 1          2
 1          1
```

As you can see the item 1 as 2 suppliers. So, What i want to do: is to select items based on first added suppliers (like in FIFO method- first in - first out)

How can do such `join query with timestamp as condition`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one record then below query should be work

```
    select product.* from product p LEFT JOIN product_supplier on product.id = itemid 
LEFT JOIN supplier ON supplierid = supplier.id 
order by registered_date ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: shoud not use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Yeah. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join . can you please go througth with above URL ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub query. In subquery use GROUP BY and Max.

```
SELECT PS.itemid, PS.supplierid, P.name, P.price, P.added_date, S.name, S.registered_date FROM product_supplier AS PS 
LEFT JOIN Product AS P ON P.id = PS.itemid
LEFT JOIN Supplier AS S ON S.id = PS.supplierid
GROUP BY PS.itemid 
ORDER BY PS.itemid LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you...

```
select  product_supplier.*, product.name, supplier.name, from 
    product_supplier 
    join product on (product_supplier.itemid = product.id)
    join supplier on (product_supplier.supplierid = supplier.id)
    order by supplier.registered_date asc
```